# gradle: "Could not determine which tasks to execute."

Tags: java, gradle

I received the following gradle build file (`gae.gradle`) with a sample project from SpringSource but when I attempt to run it with gradle as:

```
gradle gae
```

it generates the error:

```
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
```

Is this a properly formatted gradle file or am I doing something wrong?

Is it possible I should be running this with maven instead?

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'gae'

gaeVersion="1.3.5"

repositories {
    // Hibernate Validator
    mavenRepo name: 'JBoss', urls: 'https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    // GAE Jars
    mavenRepo name: 'GAE', urls:'http://maven-gae-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/repository'
}

// Remove logback as it causes security issues with GAE.
configurations.runtime.exclude(group: 'ch.qos.logback')

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5@jar',
                    "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:$gaeVersion"

    compile project(':spring-security-core'),
            project(':spring-security-web'),
            "org.springframework:spring-beans:$springVersion",
            "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion",
            "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion",
            "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion",
            "org.springframework:spring-context-support:$springVersion",
            'javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA',
            'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.1.0.Final',
            "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion"

    runtime project(':spring-security-config'),
            "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:$slf4jVersion",
            "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:$slf4jVersion"
    testCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:$gaeVersion"

    testRuntime "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:$gaeVersion",
                "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:$gaeVersion"

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try running: gradle -b gae.gradle -t

This will give you a list of the tasks which are available in this build file. Then you can run one of the tasks using: gradle -b gae.gradle *task-name*